# Como calcular duas somas com apenas um botão?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para calcular com apenas um botão duas somas diferentes, como fiz o exemplo na imagem.

Tenho o código desta forma, mas apenas com 2 números. Como faço para fazer outro cálculo em simultâneo com o mesmo botão?

```
public void calcular (View v){

        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        EditText resultado1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText15);
        String stringresultado1 = resultado1.getText().toString();

        EditText resultado2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText19);
        String stringresultado2 = resultado2.getText().toString();


        double valorresultado1, valorresultado2;


        if(stringresultado1.trim().isEmpty()){valorresultado1 = 0; } 
       else{valorresultado1 = Double.parseDouble(stringresultado1);}

        if(stringresultado2.trim().isEmpty()){valorresultado2 = 0; } 
        else{valorresultado2 = Double.parseDouble(stringresultado2);}
      if (stringresultado1.trim().isEmpty() &&stringresultado2.trim().isEmpty())
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Campos em branco",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {

            double resu = valorresultado1 + valorresultado2;


            TextView resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView32);
            resultado.setText (formatter.format(resu) + "€" );
     }

}
```

[image: tela da soma]

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza reverti sua edição pois, apesar de melhorar alguns pontos da pergunta, alterou uma caracteristica linguistica do usuario, que provavelmente é de Portugal. Recomendo que dê uma lida em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3/28595

Comment: @Articuno, sem problema, agradeço pela dica **:)**.

Comment: Quais são os `EditText` e `TextView` de cada coisa no ecrã ? Provavelmente o xml do layout tornará isso mais claro

Comment: EditText: A e B.  TextView: Resultado. Tenho o código acima, talvez ajude. Aqui a minha duvida é por o mesmo botão a calcular em simultâneo.

Comment: @Articuno No português europeu "*Gostava*" continua sendo pretérito imperfeito da mesma forma que cá no Brasil e tendo a mesmo sentido denotativo. A forma correta nos dois dialetos seria "*Gostaria*" mesmo, no futuro do pretérito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humm... confesso que não entendi direito o que você quer fazer. Mas se for o que estou pensando, o código abaixo deve funcionar (com devidas alterações dos ID's dos elementos do layout para atender ao seu problema).

```
public void calcular (View v){

        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        EditText resultadoA1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText15);
        String stringResultadoA1 = resultadoA1.getText().toString();

        EditText resultadoB1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText19);
        String stringResultadoB1 = resultadoB1.getText().toString();

        EditText resultadoA2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText23);
        String stringResultadoA2 = resultadoA2.getText().toString();

        EditText resultadoB2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText27);
        String stringResultadoB2 = resultadoB2.getText().toString();


        double valorResultadoA1, valorResultadoB1, valorResultadoA2, valorResultadoB2;


        if(stringResultadoA1.trim().isEmpty()){
            valorResultadoA1 = 0;
        }else{
            valorResultadoA1 = Double.parseDouble(stringResultadoA1);
        }

        if(stringResultadoB1.trim().isEmpty()){
            valorResultadoB1 = 0;
        }else{
            valorResultadoB1 = Double.parseDouble(stringResultadoB1);
        }

        if(stringResultadoA2.trim().isEmpty()){
            valorResultadoA2 = 0;
        }else{
            valorResultadoA2 = Double.parseDouble(stringResultadoA2);
        }

        if(stringResultadoB2.trim().isEmpty()){
            valorResultadoB2 = 0;
        }else{
            valorResultadoB2 = Double.parseDouble(stringResultadoB2);
        }

        if(stringResultadoA1.trim().isEmpty() && stringResultadoB1.trim().isEmpty() && stringResultadoA2.trim().isEmpty() && stringResultadoB2.trim().isEmpty() ){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Campos em branco", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{

            double resultado1 = valorResultadoA1 + valorResultadoB1;
            double resultado2 = valorResultadoA2 + valorResultadoB2;

            TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView32);
            TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView33);
            textView1.setText (formatter.format(resultado1) + "€" );
            textView2.setText (formatter.format(resultado2) + "€" );
        }

}
```

Comment: Adicionei ao código para calcular o resultado1 - resultado2, quando corro a aplicação no telemóvel faz-me o calculo direito, tenho adicionado ao código para guardar os número assim que saiu da aplicação mas quando volto a entrar na aplicação  o resultado1 fica direiro o resultado2 fica direito mas o resultado3 aparece igual ao resultado2, dá para explicar porque é que isto acontece??

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer um método que é responsável pelo cálculo, dando-lhe os ids dos componentes com os valores e então chamar esse método duas vezes.

```
public void calcular(View v) {
    calcular(R.id.editText15, R.id.editText19, R.id.editText32);
    calcular(R.id.editText16, R.id.editText20, R.id.editText33);
}

private void calcular(String edit1, String edit2, String viewResultado) {

    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    String entrada1 =
            ((EditText) findViewById(edit1)).getText().toString().trim();

    String entrada2 =
            ((EditText) findViewById(edit2)).getText().toString().trim();

    double valor1 = entrada1.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(entrada1);
    double valor2 = entrada2.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(entrada2);

    if (resultado1.isEmpty() || resultado2.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Campos em branco", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        double soma = valor1 + valor2;
        ((TextView) findViewById(viewResultado)).setText(formatter.format(soma) + "€");
    }
}
```

Observe também que substitui o seu `&&` por `||`. Ele deve mostrar a mensagem se pelo menos um dos campos estiver vazio, e não somente se os dois estiverem vazios.